# SharePoint online- scrolling text horizontally (marquee)

Tags: sharepoint-online, marquee

How do I have some text scrolling horizontally like marquee in SharePoint online? I am not sure what web part to use to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you consider add custom code using JQuery? - I haven't worked with SharePoint since years, but, I do remember you can add a webpart for inject JQuery / code...

Comment: I don't find any webpart to inject custom code in SharePoint online.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SharePoint online out of the box web part which supports marquee text.

To achieve your requirements, you have below two options:

1. Custom SPFx web part: Develop a custom [SPFx web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/overview-client-side-web-parts) from scratch to fit your requirements for using marquee text.
2. Use [Script editor web part for modern pages](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor): Use Script editor web part for modern pages developed by community members and add custom HTML/CSS/JS to create marquee text.

**Additional Reference**: [HTML Marquee Tag](https://www.w3schools.in/html/marquee-tag)